# Correct process for reducing SQL Log file size

Tags: sql-server, logfile

SQL 2008 R2. Full back-up every night with replication to a 2nd server for reporting. Business critical multiple databases. SQL Log files in danger of exceeding available disk space

Shrinkfile did not seem effective. Created backup of log file and then chose GUI option to shrink log file. Having done this log file size is much more manageable. When is it safe to delete the Log file backup, or is it never?

Comment: Are you referring to the transaction log?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name he seem to be mixing both questions, backups and transaction log files.

Comment: I regret that I was not clear enough originally. There are nightly backups of the databases and then much more frequent backups of the Log Files throughout the day. Having successfully (I think) reduced the Log File size (it does not seem to have grown again), when can I delete the Log File backup that was taken? Is it redundant once a new full database backup has been taken and will the new smaller Log File backup be sufficient without keeping the full backup of the Log File that I had to take to get it to shrink. Hope I have made my question (and lack of understanding) clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the transaction log backups for the full backups that you will potentially use to recover the database. E.g. if you keep the last 7 full backups, you just need to keep the log backups for the last week so you can recover the db to any point of time in the week if something is wrong.

Comment: That answers what backps to keep, but you may want to add that the transaction log size can only be reduced/shrink after the full backup.

Comment: If you backlog trx logs regularly, you don't need to shrink log file. The space will be reused after backup and the file size means SQL server needs that amount of space for the transactions during the backup period. If you shrink, the file will grow to the size again

Comment: Thank you for your answer here. I remain a little confused and would ask that you see my additional comment today against my original query. In the comment above did you mean "backup" where you wrote "backlog"? I don't believe that the Transaction Logs are normally backed up by the automated processes, only written to a backup. Sorry, I think I am confusing myself here.

Comment: The Transaction Log backup file used to be much bigger than the corresponding database backup file. Thanks to the process in my original post the Transaction Log backup file is now smaller that the corresponding database backup file and available space is less threatened. You have said above that it will just grow back to its original size, but that is not what I am seeing - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: It depends on how you backup your transaction log previously and the schedules of some database maintenance activities like DBCC checkdb. E.g., If you schedule your DBCC checkdb once a week, you may see the trx log grows a lot after that.